# How can I sum durations grouped by overlapping times in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to create a stored proc in SQL Server 2008.

I have a "Timings" Table (which could have thousands of records):

```
StaffID | MachineID | StartTime          | FinishTime
1       | 1         | 01/01/2018 12:00   | 01/01/18 14:30
2       | 1         | 01/01/2018 12:00   | 01/01/18 13:00
3       | 2         | 01/01/2018 12:00   | 01/01/18 13:00
3       | 2         | 01/01/2018 13:00   | 01/01/18 14:00
4       | 3         | 01/01/2018 12:00   | 01/01/18 12:30
5       | 3         | 01/01/2018 11:00   | 01/01/18 13:30
```

This shows how long each staff member was working on each machine.

I would like to produce a results table as below:

```
MachineID | StaffQty | TotalMins
1         | 1        | 90
1         | 2        | 60
2         | 1        | 120
3         | 1        | 120    
3         | 2        | 30
```

This would show how many minutes each machine had only one person using it, how many minutes each machine had 2 people using it etc.

Normally, I would post what I have tried so far, but all my attempts seem to be so far away, I don't think there is much point.
Obviously, I would be very grateful of a complete solution but I would also appreciate even just a little nudge in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this answers your question:

```
declare @t table (StaffID int, MachineID int, StartTime datetime2,FinishTime datetime2)
insert into @t(StaffID,MachineID,StartTime,FinishTime) values
(1,1,'2018-01-01T12:00:00','2018-01-01T14:30:00'),
(2,1,'2018-01-01T12:00:00','2018-01-01T13:00:00'),
(3,2,'2018-01-01T12:00:00','2018-01-01T12:30:00')

;With Times as (
    select MachineID,StartTime as Time from @t
    union
    select MachineID,FinishTime from @t
), Ordered as (
    select
        *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY MachineID ORDER BY Time) rn
    from Times
), Periods as (
    select
        o1.MachineID,o1.Time as StartTime,o2.Time as FinishTime
    from
        Ordered o1
            inner join
        Ordered o2
            on
                o1.MachineID = o2.MachineID and
                o1.rn = o2.rn - 1
)
select
    p.MachineID,
    p.StartTime,
    MAX(p.FinishTime) as FinishTime,
    COUNT(*) as Cnt,
    DATEDIFF(minute,p.StartTime,MAX(p.FinishTime)) as TotalMinutes
from
    @t t
        inner join
    Periods p
        on
            p.MachineID = t.MachineID and
            p.StartTime < t.FinishTime and
            t.StartTime < p.FinishTime
group by p.MachineID,p.StartTime
```

Results:

```
MachineID   StartTime                   FinishTime                  Cnt         TotalMinutes
----------- --------------------------- --------------------------- ----------- ------------
1           2018-01-01 12:00:00.0000000 2018-01-01 13:00:00.0000000 2           60
1           2018-01-01 13:00:00.0000000 2018-01-01 14:30:00.0000000 1           90
2           2018-01-01 12:00:00.0000000 2018-01-01 12:30:00.0000000 1           30
```

Hopefully you can see what each of the CTEs is doing. The only place where this may not give you exactly the results you're seeking is if one person's `FinishTime` is precisely equal to another person's `StartTime` on the same machine. Should be rare in real data hopefully.

Comment: Thank you. I will take a look and see if I can understand how it works.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work if one of the ranges completely enclose the others... I will update my question with additional sample data to illustrate what I mean.

Comment: @Gravitate - if you just care about how long the usage was for at each "occupancy" level then you can move the current final result into a CTE and make the final query `SUM(TotalMinutes)` and `GROUP BY MachineID, Cnt`

Comment: Yeah... I have done that. Hmm... I didn't think it was working but having checked with my example data it does... it must be something else I am doing wrong (or something to do with my live data that I haven't thought of). I'll get back to you. Thanks again.

Comment: Right... the problem was that I was removing your temp table and substituting in my actual table. For some reason, it goes wrong when I swap @t in the final select for my table. I know it's not the data, as if I insert it into the temp table first, there is no issue. Do you know why that might be? Using the intermediate temp table solves the problem but id rather not use it if I don't need to. Thanks again for your help so far.

Comment: @Gravitate - just checking - you're swapping `@t` in all 3 locations it's used above, right?

Comment: Twice in "Times" and once in the final select? Yes. But I can swap the 2 in "Times" without a problem. I only get incorrect results when I swap the one in the final select.

Comment: Ah... Got it... I was being stupid. Sorry. I was applying a WHERE clause to my actual table... but I forgot to apply it in the final SELECT. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

For `Sql server 2012+`,

Please mention your Sql server version.

Try my script with other sample data.
Please post other sample data if it is not working.

I think my script can be fix for other Test scenario.

```
create table #temp(StaffID int,MachineID int,StartTime datetime,FinishTime datetime)

insert into #temp VALUES

(1, 1,'01/01/2018 12:00','01/01/18 14:30')

,(2, 1,'01/01/2018 12:00','01/01/18 13:00')

,(3, 2,'01/01/2018 12:00','01/01/18 12:30')

;

WITH CTE

AS (

SELECT t.*

,t1.StaffQty

,datediff(MINUTE, t.StartTime, t.FinishTime) TotalMinutes

FROM #temp t

CROSS APPLY (

SELECT count(*) StaffQty

FROM #temp t1

WHERE t.machineid = t1.machineid

AND (

t.StartTime >= t1.StartTime

AND t.FinishTime <= t1.FinishTime

)

) t1

)

SELECT MachineID

,StaffQty

,TotalMinutes - isnull(LAG(TotalMinutes, 1) OVER (

PARTITION BY t.MachineID ORDER BY t.StartTime

,t.FinishTime

), 0)

FROM cte t

　
drop table #temp
```

for `Sql server 2008`,

```
;

WITH CTE
AS (
SELECT t.*
,t1.StaffQty
,datediff(MINUTE, t.StartTime, t.FinishTime) TotalMinutes
,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
PARTITION BY t.machineid ORDER BY t.StartTime
,t.FinishTime

) rn
FROM #temp t
CROSS APPLY (
SELECT count(*) StaffQty
FROM #temp t1
WHERE t.machineid = t1.machineid
AND (
t.StartTime >= t1.StartTime
AND t.FinishTime <= t1.FinishTime
)

) t1
)

SELECT t.MachineID
,t.StaffQty
,t.TotalMinutes - isnull(t1.TotalMinutes, 0) TotalMinutes
FROM cte t
OUTER APPLY (
SELECT TOP 1 TotalMinutes
FROM cte t1
WHERE t.MachineID = t1.machineid
AND t1.rn < t.rn
ORDER BY t1.rn DESC
) t1
```

Comment: Thank you. I will take a look. P.S. I did state the SQL Server version I am using in the first line of the question.

Comment: Not a problem. I am sure your answer will be helpful for anyone with a similar problem who are using later versions of SQL Server.

Comment: @Gravitate , you can check my sql server 2008 version.

Comment: Thank you. I will take a look.

Comment: Thank you for your help but I have selected @Damien_The_Unbeliever's answer as He answered first and I found it easier to understand. Thanks again.